# Script to wrap range of cells in HTML tags

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am searching for something like simple formatting solution. getValue(), followed by setValue() with the same data, but wrapped in HTML tags. And here is the trouble: I just can't figure out how to get range object of the cells what I need and edit them in one move. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lib for that! [SheetConverter library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter).

Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/6455765).

Here's how you could get an HTML table for your whole sheet:

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
var htmlTable = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
```

You'll find other goodies to convert ranges into arrays of formatted strings, or generate the HTML for a single cell (including fonts, background colors, text colors, and most other formatting elements).

Disclosure: I'm the library author.